# Symfony 3 - passing javascript variable to twig asset

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, templates, twig

I am passing php array with 11 elements to javascript via twig, and it works fine. Some elements of array are null, some are multidimensional arrays. This is my js code:

```
 var slot = {{ slot|json_encode|raw }}; 

        for(var i = 1; i<= 11; i++) {

            if (slot[i - 1] === null) {
                document.getElementById("slot_" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url('{{ asset('grafiki/empty.jpg') }}')";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("slot_" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url('{{ asset('grafiki/' ~ slot[1].name ~ '.jpg') }}')";
            }
        }
```

As you can see, my script is changing background images of html elements with certain id, and it works fine. 
The problem is that i have to change: `~ slot[1].name ~` to `~ slot[i-1].name ~` , but then Symfony throws error:

```
Variable "i" does not exist.
```

But when i change whole line to `console.log(slot[i-1].name)` it shows the name property of an object perfectly.

I also tried assign value to variable and then pass it to asset:

```
var name = slot[i-1].name;
document.getElementById("slot_" + i).style.backgroundImage = "url('{{ asset('grafiki/' ~ name ~ '.jpg') }}')";
```

But then I got error: `Variable "name" does not exist.`
I'm really stuck with this one, could anybody help me?

Comment: Javascript variable is available on the front side. Twig is being parsed on the backend. They do not exist in the same context.

Comment: Then why slot[1].name works? It's also javascript variable.

Comment: It is NOT a javascript variable inside those double curly brackets. Do you happen to have a twig variable `slot`?

Comment: Oh I got you. Unfortunately I named javascript array the same way twig array is named. That's where the whole misunderstand come from. It is indeed twig variable. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should sen Ajax request another endpoint for Slot variables. This endpoint return Slots json format and you can use this variables.

Comment: I know, but I want to avoid database query. Is there other way to reach images then via asset()?

Comment: Already you writing query for slots your back-end now. Only you should move query codes to endpoint for Ajax request.

Comment: Nah, I just gave up asset() function and instead i use exact directory /my_project/web/grafiki/item.jpg and javascript concatenation. It works fine. Thanks for your effort anyway.